# How do I alter the_posts_pagination based on a custom $query for posts_per_page?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I need to show a certain number of posts on my main archive page, and a different amount on each paged page.  I'm using pre_get_posts to conditionally change the query and it works great, but the problem is the the_posts_pagination() function doesn't reflect the conditions.  For simplicities sake, say I have 10 posts and I want to show one on the main page and two on the paged pages, here is my query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {

    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_post_type_archive('custom_post_type') && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( !is_paged() ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
        } else {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
        }
    }
});
```

Now, on my first archive page, the_posts_pagination() shows 10 pages because posts_per_page is set to 1.  On paged pages, it shows 5 because it posts_per_page is 2.  If you were to click on the last page (page 10) from the archive home page, you'd get a 404.  I don't believe you can hook into the_posts_pagination so how do I accurately reflect how many pages there are in my pagination?

Answer (score 1):

Your on the right track but need to also handle the `offset` to avoid the 404 errors... Here is an example of how I'm pulling this off on a site needing to display a different count on the main blog page (5 posts) vs the paged blog pages (14 posts) blog pages:

```
// custom per page and offset for paged archives
add_action('pre_get_posts', function ($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && 'blog' === $query->get('pagename') && $query->is_paged()) {
        $paged = $query->get('paged');
        $home_limit = 5;
        $paged_limit = 14;

        $offset = $paged === 2 ? $home_limit : ($paged_limit * ($paged - 1)) - $home_limit;

        $query->set('posts_per_page', $paged_limit);
        $query->set('offset', $offset);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mikerojas, that works perfectly to solve the 404's!  Are you also using pagination on that site?  My first page pagination still shows "1 2 ... 10" and secondary pages show "1 2 ... 5" because its basing it off of that "posts_per_page" param.

Comment: in my case, on the main page we are only using a "view more posts"  button that links to page 2. Only displaying pagination on the paged views.  I'll take a quick stab at modifying this to allow pagination on the main page too.